# add img tag in the middle of a php loop

Tags: php, loops, sass, php-5.6

So here is my loop. it works just fine. however I need to put an image in between this loop (just once at the parent level) and have the loop continue on

```
<?php foreach ($nav as $value){
    echo '<li><a href="'.(isset($value->uri) ? $value->uri: '#').'">'.$value->name.'</a>';
    if ($value->children->count() > 0){
        echo '<ul class="white is-dropdown-submenu menu">';
        foreach ($value->children as $child){
            echo '<li><a href="'.(isset($child->uri) ? $child->uri: '#').'">'.$child->name.'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</li>';
}; ?>
```

Comment: Add a counter. Check if the counter is in the initial state and add the image tag. Increment the counter.

Comment: Why can't you add the image outside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $counter = 0; 
  foreach ($nav as $value){
    if($counter === 0) { echo "<img/>"; }
    echo '<li><a href="'.(isset($value->uri) ? $value->uri: '#').'">'.$value->name.'</a>';a
    if ($value->children->count() > 0){
        echo '<ul class="white is-dropdown-submenu menu">';
        foreach ($value->children as $child){
            echo '<li><a href="'.(isset($child->uri) ? $child->uri: '#').'">'.$child->name.'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</li>';
    $counter++;
}; ?>
```

Comment: Another option would be adding the image after the fact with javascript.